# how to fix incompatible pointer types passing 'char [16]' to parameter of type 'FILE *' (aka 'struct __sFILE *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Tags: c

how to fix?

> warning:
>
> incompatible pointer
>            types passing 'char [16]' to parameter of type 'FILE *'
>            (aka 'struct __sFILE *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>          fread(buffer,1,512,data);
>                          ^~~~
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/
>   SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:247:90: note: 
>        passing argument to parameter '__stream' here
>    ...__ptr, size_t __size, size_t __nitems, FILE * __restrict __stream);
>                                                                 ^
>   1 warning generated.

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char readDATA[64];
    char buffer[8];
    char data[16];

    FILE *fl = fopen(data,"r");
    fgets(readDATA,64,fl);
    fread(buffer,1,512,data);
    printf("%s",readDATA);

    return 0;
}
```

I try to open a path or "random" file please help.

Comment: The definition of fread expects the last argument to be of type FILE*, so why not pass it f1?

Comment: You pass the `FILE` pointer `fl` correct to `fgets`, but not when you call [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread). Why? Is it just a typo?

Comment: `fread(buffer,1,512,data);`-> `fread(buffer,1,512,f1);`. And also you should check the return value of `fopen`, if it's `NULL` -> file coulnd not be opened.

Comment: `data` is uninitialized, which means it contains unspecified values, which means  `fopen(data,"r");` will likely overrun buffer, which is *undefined behaviour*. You also don't check if `fopen` succeeded. If it did not, then using it on `fgets` results in *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: `fread(buffer,1,512,data);` Besides your problem with last parameter, you have UB here. You read 512 bytes of data into a buffer of 8 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

According to manual page of `fread()`

> The  function  fread()  reads  nmemb  elements of data, each size bytes
>          long, from the stream pointed to by stream, storing them at  the  loca‐
>          tion given by ptr.

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

Last argument of `fread()` is the `FILE *stream` that means file from where you want to read something and store into `buffer`.

Replace

```
 fread(buffer,1,512,data); /* last argument is wrong */
```

with

```
fread(buffer,1,512,f1);
```

Also check the return value of `fopen()`

```
FILE *f1 = fopen("data","r"); /* it will try to open a file called "data" in current working directory, you can take input from user also */
if(f1 == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "file not present\n");
  return 0;
}
```

your intention may be like this

```
char data[16];/* it doesn't contain anything, so take the input from user or assign directly */
printf("enter the file name\n");
scanf("%s",data);
FILE *f1 = fopen(data,"r"); 
    if(f1 == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "file not present\n");
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: thanks! I can compile it now but when I run the command it gives me this : iTomsn0ws-iphone-4-White-N94AP:/var/mobile root# ./tryoverfl0wlvl7 ./b.txt
file not present
iTomsn0ws-iphone-4-White-N94AP:/var/mobile root#

Comment: ok. so everything is working fine. I created this program for try to exploit. but when I open a big file it only gives me "abort trap 6" and the crashlog is useless. What can I do to give me normal crashlog?

Comment: Run the executable in the `gdb` and do `bt(back trace)` it will help to find out actual cause of `abort trap`.

Comment: Thx ::::::::::::::::)

Comment: Better you can generate the `core` and analyse using `gdb`.

Comment: Welcome !! Thanks not needed, feel free to ask any other debugging help.

Comment: core /var/abc.txt
"/var/abc.txt" is not a core dump: File format not recognized
(gdb)

Comment: `abc.txt` is text file, you can't execute/run `.txt` file. First need to create binary file using `gcc -g  abc.txt` and  then run `gdb a.out`

Comment: Are you on twitter? I’m @tomitokics

Comment: Where in twitter?